# Is there a way to call a function on a model field?

Tags: django

I have a model which has a FileField and I now need to call an API to convert the file. Not sure on how to implement the function and also, how to show the file to the user after it's converted.

I was thinking of calling the function on each model object and then just changing the url in the model to the new file. Is there a way to call the function before the file is saved to the DB to make things easier?
I'm not sure if this is possible because I'm guessing that the file must be saved before it's converted.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    convertapi.api_secret = '<API KEY>'
    convertedFile = convertapi.convert('pdfa', {'File': self.file})
    self.save(update_fields=['file', 'convertedFile'])
```

Comment: If this processing takes long, you need to do this async and your scope just exploded. However, if not, then take a look at ImageField in the Django source. Add an extra file field "converted", process and store the converted file on the other field. It's not an easy task. You can also look at [Django ImageKit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit/) for ideas. Unfortunately, the scope is a bit much - I've given you a path, best to post a new question if you get stuck with specifics.

Comment: How can I call a function after the model has been saved i.e. take the saved file, convert it and then just upload it to another field to the model?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 options to implement a function to run on the model instance before it is saved.

- You can override the model's `save()` method (do what you have to do then call the super method): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods
- You can use signals. More precisely the `pre_save` signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#pre-save. The docs for how to use signals and how they work are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals

The rest of your question is a bit vague though, but hopefully this should solve your problem.

Comment: I've been trying to override the save method but it doesn't seem to work. The convert function needs the  extension and the file and it returns the file. Then I'm trying to update the file field with the new file.

Comment: This is too late, the file is already saved when pre_save/model save is called.

Comment: The file can be saved, that is not a requirement. I just thought that it would be easier for me if it's not saved but even if it is, I guess there's an update function that I can call to change the old file with the converted one.